# globalisation of format "days hours minutes ago"

Tags: globalization

I need to display a shortened version of the format "x days x hours x minutes ago" in the format of "0d 0h 0m".  This is easy enough to do but I need to take into account globalisation of this format.

Is this format recognised through-out the world and if not does anyone know if there is a standard?  Currently, I need to show a localised version for Germany, France, Poland, Italy, Sweden and Denmark.

I have tried Google without much success so any help gratefully received.